# Conditional bash search?

Tags: bash, search

How can I make such a conditional search in Bash like in Google

```
"python" imag
```

The word **python** must be in the search, while the word **imag** aims to match at least image and imaging.

I want to search a python module for images, perhaps in apt-get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grep option for searching a word is -w:

```
grep -w python | grep imag
```

Answer (score 1):

A dirty method should be use spaces. When you're looking exact words, they are likely to be between spaces. eg for apt:

```
apt-cache search " python " imag*
```

**EDIT**

A cleaner is the following:

```
apt-cache search '\<python\>' imag*
```